# How to access to functions/variables from GWT code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I am trying to use some functions from a code that has been obfuscated. So i have an html file that is calling a JS file thru the  tag:

```
<script src="gwt_svg_viewer/gwt_svg_viewer.nocache.js"></script>
```

that file is defining a function called "onScriptdownloaded" which receives a string like this:

```
gwt_svg_viewer.onScriptDownloaded(["var $wnd = window.parent;function RE(){}"]);
```

So my question is how can i access to RE? in another JS file?

It seems that there was a kind of GWT code implemented, but i am not really familiar with that.

Comment: i am not sure if  RE will always be RE or something else, since gwt compiler will obfuscate the code every time it compiles and rename function and variable. if you really want to call gwt code in a consistence manner, you will need to use jsinterop to export gwt types

Comment: @AhmadBawaneh you have opened a new world of possibilities, please set your comment as an answer in order to accept it. Per your advise JsInterop can be used to expose a Java entity and to be used inside my Java script. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names and functions in gwt will be obfuscated every time you compile your project, and variables and functions will be renamed in the process, in order to call a gwt code from javascript in a consistence manner you will need to use jsinterop to export java types. more information can be found in the [gwt jsinterop documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html)